# convert object format '2014-09-15T11:10:34Z' in pandas to string or Date-time object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this one,

### [image]

the funded_date column type is **Object**.

### [image]

I want to create anew numerical column with the year for example "2014-09-15T11:10:34Z" to "2014"

How it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer that worked or me.

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['funded_date']).dt.year
data_categoricals['year'] = df['year']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using string slicing:

```
df['year'] = df['funded_date'].str[0:4].astype(int)
```

Or try if you have nulls in your data:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['date'].str[0:4], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: It raised this error : ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @Elasri Try the second statement

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `funded_date` is a `datetime`:

```
df['funded_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['funded_date'])
```

Now use the `.year` accessor:

```
df['funded_year'] = df['funded_date'].year
```

Comment: it worked after editing the second line it should 
`df['funded_year'] = df['funded_date'].year`